# VScode automatically adding new lines on save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am facing this issue with vscode that whenever I am saving an HTML file it automatically adds the new lines. It is not because of any extension because I tested by starting vscode without extension. Below is what I am trying to say

This is how I want it to be:

```
    <li><span>X</span></li>
    <li><span>X</span></li>
    <li><span>X</span></li>
    <li><span>X</span></li>
    <li><span>X</span></li>
    <li><span>X</span></li>
```

And this is what vscode turns it into when I hit ctrl-s

```
    <li>
        <span>X</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>X</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>X</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>X</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>X</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>X</span>
    </li>
```

I have turned word-wrap off as well and tried all kinds of settings but no luck yet. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 16):

According to [this issue on VSCode's GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12076), There is an option for that since 1.8:

```json
"files.insertFinalNewline": true
```

And to be thorough, you can use all of these three settings to do most of basic formatting you usually need:

```json
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
```

<sub>NOTE: I'm aware that this may not correspond to op's description, although this question is the first hit when [searching for *vscode append new line on save* on DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vscode+append+new+line+on+save). So I felt the need to add this answer.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is a bug or what but i toggled this setting `"editor.formatOnSave": false` to `"editor.formatOnSave": true`  and then again back to `"editor.formatOnSave": false` and it stopped formatting on save.

It is weird because i did not modify any single setting and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For me, disable "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" extension fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings, it sounds like you have formatting on save turned on:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

It may be in one of several places, this issue talked through finding it: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29335

Comment: No `editor.formatOnSave` is set to false and i have not set it to true any where.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this setting worked for me

```
"html.format.enable": false
```

It's in **HTML > Format > enable/disable**

Answer (score 0):

I got here searching as to why vs code was splitting up my lines nonsensically.

There's Html>Format>Wrap Line Length which causes it to wrap at 120 chars (what is this 1980?)

Answer (score 0):

**React, Typescript, prettier, eslint, VsCode** - adding extra lines on file-save:

**Step 1, stop extra lines added on save**: Confirm prettier is saved as a `dependancy` / `dev-dependancy` in the project's `package.json`, if not install it: `npm i prettier` ~ if already included in `package.json`, run: `npm i`. **Then restart VsCode**. This stopped the extra lines added on save, defect.

**...this then caused new lint errors at each line-end.**

The following steps resolved these errors:

**Step 1,** Remove the following line `"endOfLine": "crlf",` from the project's `.prettierrc`:

```
{
  "endOfLine": "crlf", <--- removed this line
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "printWidth": 100
}
```

**Step 2, add the following to the bottom of the** `rules` object, in the project's `.eslintrc` file:

```
"prettier/prettier": [ 
    "error",
    {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
    }
]
```

**Step 3, save all changes then restart VsCode** This removed the project's line-end lint errors.

Answer (score 0):

#### VSCode: Stop adding new lines on save

- Open: Settings
- Click on: Edit in settings.json
- Add: "files.insertFinalNewline": false

```json
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "[markdown]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint"
    },
    "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": null,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": false
}
```

Comment: I forgot a step: When you open Settings, search for json settings

Comment: You can use "Edit" button to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When writing .html files please try the following:

1. Open File --> Preferences --> Settings
2. Search for "HTML -> Format: Wrap Line Length"
3. Put zero (0) into the textbox below of it to disable the wrapping.

You should have something similar like in the below image:
[Setting Wrap Line Length to zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqRAJ.png)

Let me know if this solves your problem!